# Azure VM Remote Desktop Can't Connect

Tags: azure

Following a how-to book's guide on setting up a VM through the Azure Portal and getting the error when trying to connect

> Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons: 1) Remote access to the service is not enabled 2) The remote computer is turned off [Verified through the Azure Portal it is turned on because Start is faded, while Restart and Stop are not] 3) The remote computer is not available on the network.

The error occurs before I'm able to enter any credentials - it doesn't find the IP at all.  The RDP file details (IP removed of course):

```
full address:s:[IPAddress]:3389
prompt for credentials:i:1
administrative session:i:1
```

What I've tried:

1. Even though the How-To book doesn't show where/how to specify a port, when I download the RDP file from the `Connect` option, it specifies the port 3389.  The book seems to imply that simply downloading this file and connecting will work and there's no need to specify the port.  I get the above error.
2. Flushed DNS on my computer, `ipconfig /flushdns`
3. In the Network Security Group option for the VM, I verified that port 3389 allowed any source and wasn't specific.
4. [I did miss associating the subnet part of the Network Security Group to a virtual network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal/), so I did associate my NSG with the default subnet set up for my Virtual Network.
5. From the `Quick start` option, I don't see how to connect to this either; I'm guessing, I need to specify a different port, but don't see where to do it here either => **Update: this appears to be in the Network Security Group**'s *Inbound security rules* in the Azure portal.
6. `Boot Diagnostics` option shows the login screen.  A ping to the IP address fails four times with "Request timed out."

Note: this is not a `Virtual Machine (classic)`.

Comment: Did you download the RDP file from Azure or create it by yourself?

Comment: Download, initially.  Then I edited it to change the ports based on an added `inbound security rule` in my Network Security Group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Azure portal, Select your VM -> Settings -> Boot diagnostics. Make sure that you can see the login screen. You might need to enable diagnostics (under Monitoring section) if not enabled already. 
If you don't see the login screen, trying the 'Redeploy' option under 'Support and Troubleshooting' section of settings.

If you can see that the machines has booted correctly, the connectivity issue might be because of a firewall at your end or on the VM. See if you can ping the machine. If you are behind a corporate firewall, try connecting from elsewhere and check your PC's firewall.

Creating a new Virtual Machine on the new portal now creates a NSG (Network Security Group) along with the VM. You should be able to find it under all resources, same name as you VM. Make sure that there is an Inbound rule configured for Remote desktop (it is created by default but might be worth checking).

Comment: Thanks; third one is done and verified.  I did verify the first one (boot diagnostics) and that the login screen is there.  the pings to the machines' IP address from the RDP file all fail.

Comment: just checked the pings to my VMs fails as well, however, telnet to the RDP port works. check if you can do the same: "telnet <IP> <Port>"

Answer (score 14):

just wanted to share what worked for me.

After receiving an error prompt:

> Connect is disabled for this virtual machine because of the following
>   issues: Network interface 'vmwindows1094': Network security group
>   'VMWindows10-nsg' does not have inbound security rule that allows port
>   3389. VMWindows10-nsg

I have added an inbound port rule. Under VM > Settings > Add inbound port rules.

Port: 3389 Protocol/Source/Destination: Any (this can be configured based on your security rules) Action: Allow

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but adding an inbound security rule was not sufficient (although it is also needed).
I had to go to virtual machines > (myVm) > Reset password and then choose Reset configuration only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your VM has enough memory.

I had tried all of above suggestions and still didn't manage to access.

After trying many times I managed to get in a message appeared saying:

> Your Computer is low on memory

Not 100% sure that was the reason though.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I had created an Azure VM but wasn't able to connect to it using RDP.

The culprit was a default "Inbound Port Rule" due to which all the inbound traffic was being blocked.

[image]

The solution is to create a new rule by clicking the "Add Inbound Port Rule" and allow traffic from port 3389. Make sure that the priority of this new rule is greater than the "DenyAllInBound" rule otherwise our new rule will not have any effect.

After adding the rule, try connecting to the VM using its public IP in RDP and you should be able to connect.

This worked for me, hope it helps you as well.

Comment: Hi.. I have done all the steps mentioned above still not able to login via rdp. Anyone else facing the same issue.